# How would a medieval village protect themselves from invisible monsters?

Tags: creature-design, defense, technology

How would a village of medieval-like technology protect themselves from rhino sized invisible praying mantis-like monsters?

Context and details:

The praying mantis’s have a top speed of 40 mph and unlike normal male praying mantis, they cannot fly.

These praying mantis attacks happen about once or twice every 4 months. So there is a lot of time to prepare and rebuild after attacks.

The praying mantis’s are solitary, usually attacking in numbers of only 1-3.

The praying mantis have tough armor, traditional medieval weapons don’t have much of an effect.

The mantis’s can turn invisible at will but while moving or in contact with other beings/structures they are semi-visible.

The mantis are attacking these villages for territorial means and for a bit of extra food.

The mantis’s navigate mainly with electroreception and night vision.

The weapons available to the villagers are what you would think of as standard medieval weapons. IE swords, spears, hammers, etc. no gunpowder.

The question is asking for a broader answer as what I’m looking for is a way multiple different villages of different shapes and sizes could defend themselves. For a standard basis think around 100-300 occupants.

Answers should not be overly specific including things like “hide in a tree over there” or “build fortifications around a bridge on the river over there.” This is becuase of the previous detail.

The skills of the villagers are what you would expect of medieval villagers. There are farmers, tanners, blacksmiths, a handful of village guards, etc…

The mantis’s arrived in the vicinity of the villages after the villages had already been constructed. They are a relatively new threat.

This does not take place on earth, but a fictional world.

The praying mantis monsters are NOT actual scaled up praying mantis’s. I just call them that cause when not invisible they have a similar look and body plan to praying mantis’s.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the basis of the Predator. Yes, that Schwarzenegger film. Really, you do the same thing to the large mantis that you do to the predator. You make it so its invisibility is useless. Mud slingers, Water methods, anything to stir up enough flying junk that a huge invisible monster would just get covered in it and render its special ability at least a little less useful.

Comment: What is the intelligence/cognitive/sentient level of these creatures? Are they pure instinct, or can they consciously alter their behavior?

Comment: They have intelligence similar to cats or dumb dogs. They rely a lot on instinct but can alter behavior if need be.

Comment: Cats are far smarter than dogs. Cats can plan and conspire, and alter goals depending on the circumstances. A cat has the cunning intelligence of a three or four year old human and can 'count' up to at least five (understand there are five, not six or four, things). .At the size of a rhino, they would be a formidable opponent indeed. A dog the size of a rhino would need a human to train it.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond perhaps, but google tells me dogs are  more intelligent as their brain size is larger and is packed denser with neurons.

Comment: Cats have a single hemisphere, dogs have two. Thus, in spatial wholistic things, cats have an advantage. The thing about cats is that they really have no motivation to cooperate with humans in any intelligence testing.

Comment: But anyone who owns cats and dogs will tell you the cat outsmarts the dog every time.

Comment: Intelligence is equivocal and can be perceived through many different perspectives such as planning, IQ, EQ, memory, sentience, etc… let it never known if cats or dogs are smarter.

Comment: When you say they "can turn invisible at will" what do you actually mean? Does dust or smoke in the air reveal their outline? If they were sprayed with paint would that reveal them, or would the paint become invisible too? Please give us details on what you mean by invisible.

Comment: By turning invisible I mean just that. *They* turn invisible. My question gives all that is needed to know, when in contact with other objects/beings they become semi visible. This is a good thing becuase not only is spraying them with paint leave the paint visible, but it also renders their ability to use their invisibility to its fullest.

Comment: You've told us a lot about your monsters, you've told us nothing about the village, its inhabitants, their skills, what resources are available to them, the geology and ecology of the region.... The medieval era was from approximately 500 ce to 1500 ce. That's 1,000 years of technological innovation (in the beginning they had swords & spears, at the end they had muskets and canon...). So you need to tell us the specific year. You need to explain any alliances or feudal dependencies. And then you need to remember we help build worlds, not tell stories ([help/on-topic]).

Comment: traditional medieval weapons includes trebuchet and cannons so you may want to be more specific. also you have one of humanities most effective hunting tools, fire.

Comment: Trebuchet, yes, but I specifically said no gunpowder so cannons are out of question. Even if they saw use, cannons and trebuchets probably wouldn’t be that effective against a mobile invisible enemy.

Comment: `The question is asking for a broader answer as what I’m looking for is a way multiple different villages of different shapes and sizes could defend themselves. For a standard basis think around 100-300 occupants.` That's a VTC:Needs More Focus. Stack Exchange doesn't do broad. At all. Questions are expected to be focused and specific (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: Please understand, questions like this are difficult for Stack Exchange. Is it raining? snowing? is the attack during the day or night? Is the temperature outside comfortable? Hot? freezing cold? Is the village suffering illness? There are far too many variables. Why can't you answer this question for yourself? What is the real problem we're trying to solve? Because anything including wrestling will work.

Comment: First of all there are a lot of variables, what’s so bad about that? Willik and Tom all managed to give perfectly reasonable answers that would work no matter if it’s snowing, raining, sunny, cloudy, night, or day. Difficult for stack exchange huh? This question has 6 answers all of which make perfect sense.

Comment: Giant invisible mantis-eating birds. Duh.

Comment: @HomegrownPotatoes You missed the point. Stack Exchange has rules. If you don't like them, you're welcome to use another service. Few of the answers are actually valuable: Sexy decoy (silly), they'd move (violates premise), your mantis aren't really invisible (violates premise), there wouldn't be a village (violates premise), moat (duplicate), and poison (duplicate). So, out of the 8 answers at this time, 6 aren't valuable. That's a 25% success rate. Stack Exchange has rules for a reason. They prefer to see a 90% success rate to meet their business goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Poison.**

Your invisible creatures are much like lions.  They are predators.  They eat what they kill.

You can poison them.

http://www.livingwithlions.org/lion-poisoning.html

> When lions or hyenas kill a large animal like a cow, they eat part of
> it and return the next night to finish the carcass. Livestock owners
> have learned that the universally available agricultural pesticide
> carbofuran (marketed as Furadan) is lethal to predators – they need
> only sprinkle a few cents worth of carbofuran on the carcass and any
> mammal or bird which feeds on it will die.
>
> This cow (right), found by one of LWL's Lion Guardians, was killed by
> lions and partially eaten. They returned to the carcass the next
> night, providing an easy opportunity for a potential lion poisoner.
>
> LWL has evidence of over 50 lions poisoned in just our Laikipia study
> area, and at least 68 in our Kilimanjaro study area since 2001,
> sometimes whole prides at once.

The pygmy goats that have long wandered the outskirts of your medieval village now finally have a use.  You will send kids out every few days to paint the goats with carbofuran.  Goats do not usually eat other goats and you want the ones that do to quit it anyway.  But invisible monsters that eat goats will get poisoned and die.

If the attacks are happening in the village, then you need to let the goats into the village.  It is a bummer after you spent so much time trying to keep them out but you can let them have this small victory.

Comment: This answer's only weakness is the obvious anti-goat bias. If letting goats have the run of the town and eat other goats isn't solving the problem, you aren't using enough of it.

Answer (score 4):

### They would move

I suspect this isn't the answer you're looking for, but the scenario you describe is pretty horrifying:

- Every couple of months a swarm of gargantuan, armored, *invisible* predators attacks the community, killing and probably eating several people.

Unless there is some extremely compelling reason for the community to stay rooted in that exact location, they are going to relocate as soon as it becomes clear that the attacks are a recurring thing rather than a single freak occurrence.

Think about how much grief there will be in that town, with many families mourning the loss of somebody who was dragged away screaming in the night, or trampled to a pulp. Maybe later some of their partial remains are discovered by woodsmen or farmers.

Think also about how terrifying this would be, since the monsters are invisible. Imaginations will run wild as to the nature and motivations of these creatures, and IMHO it's overwhelmingly likely the community will settle on a religious narrative: these things are *demons* sent from Hell by The Devil to destroy them.

Nobody in the town is going to propose the suicidal notion of staying and fighting. Nobody will say something stupid about refusing to let anyone or anything force them out of their own home. You can farm this plot of land just as easily as one that isn't being terrorized by an army of demons.

Everybody will pack up and move in the direction of the nearest town that isn't regularly attacked by hungry invisible monsters.

They *might* bury the dead first, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Honestly, you'd probably have a hard time getting enough people to sign up to get to town size in the first place. The third or fourth time an expedition vanished trying to find the remains of the last expedition who tried founding a settlement there, people would start to take the hint.

Comment: @Cadence probably should have included it in the question earlier but the mantis’s arrived long after the village was already settled.

Answer (score 4):

## Sexy MAN-tis Decoy

[image]

If I were The Mantis God, I would tell my mantises to pick a random spot in the grain fields and turn invisible. When the farmer walks by, snatch him up and eat his face off. Then run away and come back four months later. Choose a different place next month.

This is unfeasible to defend against. Every farmer needs an escort of a dozen or so soldiers to kill the monster before the monster eats the farmer. And they must be alert at all times. The monster can snatch up a farmer and escape in seconds.

You cannot run a medieval village under these conditions. Even if they can somehow equip enough soldiers, they cannot grow enough food to feed everyone. The mantises can turn invisible and be anywhere at any time. Perhaps you could build a curtain wall around all the fields, to keep all visible and invisible intruders out. But that does not sound like a medieval village any more.

Since you want the mantises to be defeatable, I suggest there is no The Mantis God telling them what to do. They are stupid animals and are easy to predict. This is how we protect ourselves.

For example the mantises only attack at night when we are inside our fortified huts. Or they will always fall prey to a scarecrow shaped like a sexy MAN-tis with the shiniest carapace and the most delicate pincers. Phfoar, he looks single and ready to mingle. The body is full of straw but the head is full of poison!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Good, filled moat, with fixed stakes below the surface and ramparts with Ballistas/archers.

They cannot fly - so traversing any form of water body, even a really big puddle, is going to indicate to the defenders where they are. A Hail of Arrows is likely to provide either enough of a nuisance or hit a vulnerable part.

In the case of a Ballista - there was a report from Roman usage of one going clean through the armor of a soldier (Breast plate and back plate) and then going halfway through a tree trunk. A Roman ballista has more than enough power to punch through any natural armor - or at least, really make the Mantises think about going for an easier meal.

The fixed stakes below the surface are more in case they decide to swim across.

In terms of access across the moat, instead of a traditional drawbridge, the entranceway would be like a paddling pool, only a couple of CM deep - more than enough for the inhabitants to cross with their platform-style shoes, but enough that if a beast tries to cross, they have a few seconds of warning to drop the portcullis and start raining hell down on them.

Answer (score 1):

Baited poison traps as in a few other answers are probably the best solution, but if you are looking for something a little more dramatic then it depends on one line in your question

> The mantis’s can turn invisible at will but while moving or in contact with other beings/structures they are semi-visible.

This means they are only really invisible when standing still and not touching anything, this implies that with a good system of lookouts you should be able to spot them approaching and then tag them with a spear with a flag on the end so that you can tell where they are if they turn invisible again.  If you can't penetrate the skin with a thrown spear then just use something sticky on the end.
At that point it's a question of finding a weapon with the stopping power required, which would probably be large crossbow/ballista probably with a poison tip to bring them down.

If no weapons are able to penetrate their armour then they would use fire to either kill them or drive them into a pit trap they can't escape from

Answer (score 0):

poison, mud, water, watching for footprints, etc.

They seem at once too strong and too weak though. If *all* medieval weapons can't touch them, then your world has weird physics (I guess that's not bad, but something to keep in mind), at the same time, since they are vulnerable to poison, and bother humans so much they'd probably go extinct pretty soon, at least the man attacking ones.

Maybe they only exist on the outskirts of civilization and pray on people who are forced to live in the edge due to human politics.

Like man-eating tigers or something.

Answer (score 0):

by not existing in the first place...

Because to form, to make that village you need good, supporting conditions. People are disorganized and vulnerable in that time, I don't think in condition that dangerous it would be possible in the first place.

This village would appear somewhere else, and later, with some good (but primitive) paramilitary structure this particular region would be explored and possibly cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

**The Motte and Bailey:**

The Motte-and-Bailey is a type of fortification that, according to Wikipedia, should be relatively easy to build. It consists of a heavily fortified wood or stone structure (Called a keep) constructed upon a hilltop (if there are no hills nearby, those can be constructed by moving sufficient amounts of earth). Around the keep is a wide expanse where your people go about their business. This is also surrounded by a defensive wooden palisade and a ditch. When your village is under attack, the villagers retreat to the fortified keep until either the creatures leave of their own accord or the defenders can repel the attack. So, one possibility is to simply wait out the attack in a reinforced keep.

Now, as for possible means of repelling an attack instead of waiting one out, ideally you want your ditch filled with water so that any creatures traversing it leave an obvious indication of where they are. As another answer mentioned, fixed stakes in the ditch are also good to have. As for weapons that can be used against them, there are of course siege engines such as ballistae, which should have enough firepower to pierce through the creatures' armor. Incendiary weapons are also an option. Burning pitch or tar can be launched at the creatures if they even bother trying to break down the outer walls.